# Find most common string in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Im making a 2D numpy array in python which looks like this

```
['0.001251993149471442' 'herfst'] ['0.002232327408019874' 'herfst'] ['0.002232327408019874' 'herfst'] ['0.002232327408019874' 'winter'] ['0.002232327408019874' 'winter']
```

I want to get the most common string from the entire array.
I did find some ways to do this already but all of those have the same problem that it wont work because there are 2 datatypes in the array.

Is there an easier way to get the most common element from an entire column (not row) besides just running it through a for loop and counting?

Comment: Please show what you tried, and the problem. By the look of it, I see a single data type which is `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a count of all the values using numpy and collections. It's not clear from your question whether the numeric values in your 2D list are actually numbers or strings, but this works for both as long as the numeric values are first and the words are second:

```py
import numpy
from collections import Counter

input1 = [['0.001251993149471442', 'herfst'], ['0.002232327408019874', 'herfst'], ['0.002232327408019874', 'herfst'], ['0.002232327408019874', 'winter'], ['0.002232327408019874', 'winter']]
input2 = [[0.001251993149471442, 'herfst'], [0.002232327408019874, 'herfst'], [0.002232327408019874, 'herfst'], [0.002232327408019874, 'winter'], [0.002232327408019874, 'winter']]

def count(input):
  oneDim = list(numpy.ndarray.flatten(numpy.array(input))) # flatten the list
  del oneDim[0::2]                                         # remove the 'numbers' (i.e. elements at even indices)
  counts = Counter(oneDim)                                 # get a count of all unique elements
  maxString = counts.most_common(1)[0]                     # find the most common one
  print(maxString)

count(input1)
count(input2)
```

If you want to also include the numbers in the count, simply skip the line `del oneDim[0::2]`

Comment: Oh, those are integers, thanks for ur help

Comment: Glad I could help! Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mode()` method exists only in *Pandas*, not in *Numpy*,
so the first step is to flatten your array (*arr*) and convert it to
a pandasonic *Series*:

```
s = pd.Series(arr.flatten())
```

Then if you want to find the most common string (and note that *Numpy*
arrays have all elements of the same type), the most intuitive solution
is to execute:

```
s.mode()[0]
```

(*s.mode()* alone returns a *Series*, so we just take the initial element
of it).

The result is:

```
'0.002232327408019874'
```

But if you want to leave out strings that are convertible to numbers,
you need a different approach.

Unfortunately, you can not use *s.str.isnumeric()* because it finds
strings composed **solely** of digits, but your "numeric" strings contain
also dots.

So you have to narrow down your Series (*s*) using *str.match* and
then invoke *mode*:

```
s[~s.str.match('^[+-]?(?:\d|\d+\.\d*|\d*\.\d+)$')].mode()[0]
```

This time the result is:

```
'herfst'
```